# Check if a given date is in Day Light Savings or Not in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to know if the data in the columns (below) are in Daylight Savings or not

Column names : Start date , End date

Answer (score 0):

As stated, your question fails to acknowledge that there are a lot of different definitions of Daylight Savings time.  I wish I could find the article -- there was a great interview with the original maintainers of the DST tables about how they were actually taking guesses in many parts of the world.

The timezone package in Debian and others defines many of these rules to the best ability of the given authorities.

My advice: convert all dates to a known timezone using authoritative tools (UTC is the typical case; or secondary your local time zone), and do all your calculations based on that, without trying to understand the 120+ different timezone definitions.

If you really want to know if a given date is in a DST situation, I would convert the date to a given timezone, format it with a DST extension (e.g. MDT/MST for Mountain Daylight Time or Mountain Standard Time) and look for the MDT/MST suffix to determine daylight-ness.  You'll have to define which locale you want daylight-ness, however as the cutoff day varies from locale to locale.